# Error during build: EPERM: vite import glob (operation not permitted, scandir)

Tags: vue.js, npm, build, glob, vite

When building my app for production,
running `npm rum build` I get an error.

### Error

```
vite v3.0.7 building for production...
✓ 29 modules transformed.
[vite:import-glob] EPERM: operation not permitted, scandir 'C:\Documents and Settings'
file: C:/Users/…/src/views/Room.vue
error during build:
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, scandir 'C:\Documents and Settings'
```

**I am using** Vue 3 + Vite, npm, VSCode.
Working fine in dev mode.

### I tried  this solutions but none worked:

reinstall npm, vscode, restarting, config prefix, run as admin, gitbash, full rights…

### My code

inside script of Room.vue :

`roomImages.value = import.meta.glob("../assets/rooms/romantique/*.(jpg|JPG|png|PNG)",{ as: "url" });`

package.json

```
{
  "name": "site-name",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview --port 4173",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .vue,.js,.jsx,.cjs,.mjs --fix --ignore-path .gitignore"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@quasar/extras": "^1.15.1",
    "pinia": "^2.0.17",
    "quasar": "^2.7.7",
    "vue": "^3.2.37",
    "vue-router": "^4.1.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@quasar/vite-plugin": "^1.1.1",
    "@rushstack/eslint-patch": "^1.1.4",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^3.0.1",
    "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "^7.0.0",
    "eslint": "^8.21.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^9.3.0",
    "prettier": "^2.7.1",
    "sass": "^1.54.4",
    "vite": "^3.0.4"
  }
}
```

Any clues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit late, but here is a workaround.

For the dynamic image(s) you want to display from a folder (for example src/Assets/images/ with 1 image in the folder), proceed like below:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <img :src="getImageUrl(path)">
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
let imagesUrl = import.meta.glob("../assets/images/*.(jpg|JPG|png|PNG|svg)", { as: "url", eager: true });

let path = "../assets/images/logo.svg";

function getImageUrl(subPath) {
    return imagesUrl[subPath];
}
</script>
```

Problem was the use of import.meta.glob with dynamic images paths.

More details here https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/10306#issue-1393503174